# Storing and retrieving voice alerts

Tags: twilio, playback, voice, recording, replay

I want to store a voice messages in voice-table (MySQL)  and users should be able to dial a number and get back the stored messages

can you help me with voice recording and playing it back in Twilio?

Is there any limitations on how much recording can be done or can the maximum recording, replay be controlled ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The  verb has a max length attribute as you can see [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-maxlength).

It is defaulted to 3600 seconds (1 hour). On the  [verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record), you can specify the length of the record by changing the maxLength attribute. Make sure however that if you want to transcribe your recording it doesn;t exceed 120 seconds as you will get a warning if it exceeds that. We have records of people recording up to 4 hours.

To record a call in PHP, all you need to do is return the Record verb on your TwiML. Take a look at [this quick start](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/record-caller-leave-message) that shows you how to record a call using PHP.

You can then Play this recording later on by using the  verb as shown [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/twiml/play-mp3-for-caller).

Hope this helps you.